# "Server not found" errors all over after Wordpress installation

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I uploaded my Wordpress blog from my local machine to Slicehost and then pointed the domain name to the IP address. Then I installed the blog as normal. Once I went to wp-login.php to login, though, I started getting "Server not found" errors. That was strange because the server process was still running, and I checked many times. I can't see anything wrong in the error log, or the access log either.

This doesn't only affect Wordpress. I can't access phpmyadmin either now, which was mapped to a subdirectory of the same domain address.

What is going on? Can anyone help?

Edit: the blog is located on a subdomain. It's still accessible from IP address. The virtual host configs are ServerName and ServerAlias, both set to blog.mysite.com. When I changed those and restarted apache, phpmyadmin came back.

Edit: also it's not a propagation issue because I installed the blog from the domain name. It's only when I tried to log into the admin section, I started getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had entered DNS information both at GoDaddy and at Slicehost. Deleting Slicehost DNS record fixed this issue.